# does implementing grails rest controllers needs changes in the UrlMappings?

Tags: rest, grails

I am trying to imeplement a rest controller in grails 2.3.7. I have a simple controller, same actions as of a scaffolded one, nothing special.

My problem is I am not able to call show, update, delete and save actions via:

```
GET to localhost:8080/proj/domain/1

PUT/DELETE to localhost:8080/proj/domain/1

POST to localhost:8080/proj/domain
```

However it works when I add this to the url in UrlMappings.groovy

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        action = [POST:"save",GET:'show',DELETE:"delete"]
    }
```

Im following with the grails doc's '8.1.5 Implementing REST controllers'. Based on my understanding of it, it should work without doing further configurations outside of the controller. Is modifying the url mappings necessary?

Comment: You asked if you need to change your URL mappings but haven't shown what your URL mappings look like so there is no way to know if your current mappings should work or not.

Comment: I have updated the question to includes the urlmappings

Comment: What does "not able to call" mean?  Are you getting 404, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes adding a REST controller requires you to add a URL mapping for the resource, defining it as either singular or multi resource. Example:

```
“/foo”(resource:”foo”)
```

Or

```
“/foos”(resources:”foo”)
```

You can run `url-mappings-report` to see the URL mappings this produces